# Fatal error after update

Tags: fatal-error

My client updated her site on her own, and it went down. There were lots of error messages, I found many missing files and put them up, those errors went away, and now this is the error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function determine_locale() in
>   /home/content/04/5575704/html/wp-includes/script-loader.php on line
>   1096

Comment: What did the client update? What version of Wordpress is the client using right now?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like something went wrong during update and not all files are on the server or some of them are corrupted.

1. Go to wordpress.org and download a package with WP.
2. Go login to FTP of your clients site.
3. Delete `wp-includes` and `wp-admin` directories.
4. Upload these directories from original WP package.
5. Upload all files in root directory of that package (`index.php`, `wp-activate.php` and so on).

After these steps everything should be fine.